# How to print a "Continuous from previous page" in the body of the subsequent pages in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

In **SSRS 2008 R2** How do I print a "Continuous from previous page" in the body of the subsequent pages if the group continues on more than one page. I am able to print in the page header and not in the body section. Thanks in advance.